# FIltering on User Selection in Ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I need some help desperately and I'm a novice soooo I need to laid out pretty plainly for my simple mind.

I have an app that uses ng-repeat to show a list of content that is brought in my a json file. There are different pieces in the json file that the user would want to filter by so I created a modal that pops up and gives the user longs of option to filter by. I am assuming they would act like booleans and toggle on and off on click.

I need to take the info from that modal and filter the ng-repeat based on what the user selects on that modal.

I did some research and saw that there is a "| Filter" option but honestly I'm pretty lost. Can anyone help or help me do it?

Comment: Show us some code, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Honestly it is all crap and like I said I'm super new so I got mad and deleted my progress... :(

Answer (score 0):

The filter named filter is an angular standard that allow you to "Select a subset of items from an array" (according to the documentation)

All filter have the same concept : it take an input, do some action and give you a result.

for the `ng-repeat` directive, you can use the filter `filter` to select items you want to display.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search">
<div ng-repeat="oneObject in listObject | filter:search">
```

If you want to filter on a specific property of object in the array you can make something similar to :

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search.propertyname">
<div ng-repeat="object in listObject | filter:search">
```

Comment: That makes sense to me, I just think it is above my pay grade. I am going to need to find a dev to pay to help me. This project is on hold because I can't figure it out and I just noticed there is someone else doing something similar.... with is unfortunate because it looks like they have a team and money